# CSS3 jQuery animation by non specific amount

Tags: jquery, css, rotation

When I use jQuery animations I often use += to tell an element to change by a certain amount. For example:

```
$('div').animate({top, '+=100px'}, 1000, 'linear');
```

I'm using the rotate feature of CSS3 in an animation. Is there a way to do something like the += feature of jQuery?

For example if I have 3 divs all initially rotated at different angles and on hover, I want them all to rotate a further 10 degrees. I can't set rotate(10deg) on all of them because that will just rotate them all to the same point.

Comment: See [move.js](http://visionmedia.github.com/move.js/).

Comment: I don't think this is possible in CSS3, but why not do this in JS?

Comment: Yeh I might have to. Just thought it would be cleaner if possible in CSS3.